# Python can i present bokeh plotting outside jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, bokeh

I've been using bokeh to plot data on a map using bokeh.

Is there a way to work with this library outside jupyter notebook?

Something like in Pychram and saving the plot to HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bokeh can generate complete HTML pages for Bokeh documents using the `file_html()` function. you can refer [Embedding Plots and Apps](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/1.3.2/docs/user_guide/embed.html) for more detail.

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import file_html

plot = figure()
plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

html = file_html(plot, CDN, "my plot")
```